# C# IQueryable check in OrderBy for null ckeck

Tags: c#

IQueryable throw "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Code:

```
public IQueryable<T> ApplyOrder(IQueryable<T> items, GridSortDirection direction)
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case GridSortDirection.Ascending:
                    return items.OrderBy(_expression);
                case GridSortDirection.Descending:
                    return items.OrderByDescending(_expression);
            }
        }
```

where _expression is type of:

```
Expression<Func<T, TKey>> expression
```

and this is

```
{x => x.customers.studentschoolenrolments.ElementAt(0).schools.Name}
```

I don't want this exeption. Is it possible to check if element exist and if not return empty string back?

I try to use method like:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
    return items == null || !items.Any();
}
```

but I have no idea how to use it in `items.OrderBy(_expression);`

Comment: I think the only way you could do it is if you surface that school name into a Select() and order the result of that.

Comment: I think you should check expression dynamically for null check for generic solution.

Comment: @MaDeRkAn how? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My head likes to mix up `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`, so this maybe nonsense (but I don't see any db-tags). Can't you use `FirstOrDefault` like this:

```
{x => x.customers.studentschoolenrolments.FirstOrDefault()?.schools.Name ?? string.Empty}
```

Comment: `?.` can't be used in any expression tree, regardless of what query provider it will be used with. But the OP does appear to be compiling and executing the query directly, in which case re-working the code to avoid `IQueryable`, instead just using `IEnumerable`, allows your answer to work.

Comment: What if studentschoolenrolments or schools null ?

Comment: @MaDeRkAn if the `?.` operator can be used at all, it can also be used consecutively `studentschoolenrolments?.FirstOrDefault()?.schools?.Name ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @hvd thanks for that hint. I was actually more worried if `FirstOrDefault()` and `??` can be used in that query/expression.

Comment: I take it as an answer even if I change the method.